# How to compile TypeLite T4 template in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, typescript, code-generation, t4, typelite

I want to create `.d.ts` file for all my C# DTOs during build automaticly usign TypeLite. My **Contract.tt** is slightly minified original file from installation of [TypeLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TypeLite) Nuget package:

```
    <#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="True" language="C#" #> 
    <#@ assembly name="TypeLite.dll" #>
    <#@ assembly name="TypeLite.Net4.dll" #>
    <#@ assembly name="My.Contract.dll" #>

    <#@ import namespace="TypeLite" #> 
    <#@ import namespace="TypeLite.Net4" #> 
    <#@output extension=".d.ts"#>

    <#@include file="Manager.ttinclude"#>
    <#
    var manager = Manager.Create(Host, GenerationEnvironment);
    var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
        .WithReference("Enums.ts")
        .ForLoadedAssemblies();
    #>
    <#= ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Properties) #>

    <# manager.StartNewFile("Enums.ts"); #>
    <#= ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Enums) #>
    <# manager.EndBlock(); #>
    <# manager.Process(true); #>
```

Following [MS Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx) and [this article](http://netitude.bc3tech.net/2013/06/15/t4-gotchyas-in-your-environment/) I've added following code to my MSbuild procedure:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <T4ReferencePath Include="$(SolutionDir)\My.Contract\bin\$(Configuration)">
    <InProject>False</InProject>
  </T4ReferencePath>

  <None Include="$(SolutionDir)\Scripts\Contract.tt">
    <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
    <OutputFilePath>$(SolutionDir)\Scripts</OutputFilePath>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>

<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

But unfortunately I recive this error:

```
Error   14  Running transformation: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Could not obtain DTE from host
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating<cut>.GeneratedTextTransformation.Manager.VSManager..ctor
```

Which looks like the T4 template is expected to be executed only in VisualStudio. Is there A way to run TypeLite compilation with MSBuild?

Comment: The only way to get the T4 templates running in the build is to install VS SDK and then Modeling SDK, isn't it? Am I missing something?

Comment: I am getting this error "Compiling transformation: Metadata file '$(TargetDir)TypeLite.dll' could not be found. Line=0, Column=0". Any ideas? I believe I might be setting the T4ReferencePath wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in **[Manager.ttinclude](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/11/06/multiple-outputs-from-t4-made-easy-revisited)**, which is responsible for splitting T4 output in multiple files and automatically adding them to the project. This requires DTE which is not part of MSBuild target in [Modeling SDK for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40754).

So I just removed `manager` and created 2 separate templates. Instead of `Contract.tt` I got:

**Enums.tt**:

```
    <#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="True" language="C#" #>
    <#@ assembly name="TypeLite.dll" #>
    <#@ assembly name="TypeLite.Net4.dll" #>
    <#@ assembly name="CC.Business.Contract.dll" #>

    <#@ import namespace="TypeLite" #> 
    <#@ import namespace="TypeLite.Net4" #> 
    <#@output extension=".ts"#>

    <#
        var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
            .ForLoadedAssemblies();
    #>
    <#= ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Enums) #>
```

And **Models.tts**:

```
    <#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="True" language="C#" #>
    <#@ assembly name="TypeLite.dll" #>
    <#@ assembly name="TypeLite.Net4.dll" #>
    <#@ assembly name="CC.Business.Contract.dll" #>

    <#@ import namespace="TypeLite" #> 
    <#@ import namespace="TypeLite.Net4" #> 
    <#@output extension=".d.ts"#>

    <#
        var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
            .WithReference("Enums.ts")
            .ForLoadedAssemblies();
    #>
    <#= ts.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Properties) #>
```